# Write a mongodb query to search documents with matching collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is the image of the search page where the user is going to select search criteria. Selecting all select fields are not required. A user can select the search criteria he wants.

[image]

On the basis of users selection, we need to search the data from MongoDB.
I tried the MongoDB query as below, but I am not getting results as I am expecting.

Here is the Code :

```
Users.find({
        $or: [
            {VillageOrCity : VillageOrCity},
            { District: District },
            { Tehsil: Tehsil },
            { Constituency: Constituency },
            { Caste: Caste },
            { CasteCategory: CasteCategory  }
        ]
    },
    function(err,data){
        if(err){
            console.log(error);
        }   
        else{
            console.log(data);
            //res.send(data);
            res.render('searchResults',{data: data});
        }
    });
```

Can anyone please help to solve this problem.

Comment: What are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: expecting to get all documents where at least one condition matches from the search results